# Popup window after JavaScript validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a form with JavaScript validation (Checkvals) function and after JavaScript validation i need to make a jQuery popup window for confirmation. Can some one help me with condition to check if JavaScript validation is complete and valid then pop up screen?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#dialog').dialog  ({
      autoOpen: false,  
      width: 400,  
      modal: true,   
      resizable: false,   
      buttons: {    
         "Print Request Letter": function() { 
            document.LetterRequest.submit();  
         }, 
         "Cancel": function() {  
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
         }    
      }    
   });   
   $("#LetterRequest").submit(function(e){    
      if (!CheckVals() return false) {    
         e.preventDefault();    
         $("#dialog-confirm").html($('.NoOfLetters').val()); 
         $('#dialog').dialog('open');   
      }          
   });     
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by       `if (!CheckVals() return false) { `? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Consider adding more info, so that we know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
$("#LetterRequest").submit(function(e){    
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!CheckVals()) return false; // validation fails and stop execution
    else
    {
        $("#dialog-confirm").html($('.NoOfLetters').val()); 
        $('#dialog').dialog('open'); // opens the dialog
    }
});
```

and also in buttons, you should use

```
$("#LetterRequest")[0].submit();
```

instead of

```
document.LetterRequest.submit();
```

Comment: On click submit i was using the JavaScript Validation and simultaneously this popup window is also displayed .. so is there any way that only after completion of javaScript Validation and if form is valid i need to popup the confirmation window..for the above solution i am still getting the popup window before its been validated.

Comment: What you are returning from the `CheckVals()` function, you should use `return false` for validation fail and `return true` for validastion success.

Comment: Add `return true` at the end of the `CheckVals()` function and I think it's working in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8h8qN/1/) and also your `CheckVals()` is to big so if incase there is any errors then you should solve it but as you said that dialog displays before validation completes, it's now working fine.

Comment: Hi Sheikh !the above code works but i am having an issue ..once i fill in the missing data upon validation alert in form and try to submit again .. its not doing anything (form is not been submitted again ) .. bcoz in if condition we haven;t mentioned any thing to do..

Comment: It's submitting in the fiddle if the `CheckVals()` returns true, when the validation succeeded the form should be submitted.

Comment: This `$("#LetterRequest")[0].submit();` will submit the form if `CheckVals()` returns true/validation success.